# Replacing spaces with underscores using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XSLT I am folding two data elements together to create a filename to import an image. The following  template concatenates the elements and converts any upper case letters to lowercase using a variable. But some Surname and FirstName elements have spaces in them that we need to replace with "_" (underscores). How do I add that capability to this function?

Here's the template (I included the variable for reference):

```
...<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />...

<xsl:template match="Consultant">
<consultant>
<consultantphoto>
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:text>file://images/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Surname, $uppercase, $smallcase)"/>
<xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(FirstName, $uppercase, $smallcase)"/>    
<xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
</consultantphoto>
</xsl:text>
</consultant>
</xsl:template>
```

This template results in an XML image reference like: `<consultant href="file://surname_firstName" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another character space in uppercase and underscore("_") in smallcase:

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '" />
```

Comment: Actually, switch your answer and you have it correct! The space should be in the "uppercase" variable and the underscore in the "lowercase".

Comment: Can you also use this technique to remove characters? Some of the names have "," (commas) and "." (periods) in them that need to be removed.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. you can use the same $smallcase as given above, and change $uppercase to following:
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ,.'" />

Comment: So, this is how it is going to work: 
"A" gets replaced with "a" ;
 "B" gets replaced with "b" ;
 " " replaced with "_" ;
 "," replaced with "" ;
 "." replaced with "".

Comment: Yes, got it. It works like a charm. I'm also using it to replace foreign characters.

My XML contains some CR entities `&#13;` Is there a way to strip them out of the data?

Comment: You can add "&#13;" at the end of $uppercase(just like "," and "." were added).

Comment: So, spaces, commas and entities go into separate quotes?

Comment: i meant this: <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ,.&#13;'" />

Comment: To replace the comma and the period do you insert "" in the other variable? If not how do you represent "nothing"?

Comment: OK, translate() replaces characters based on indexes. For example, if "A" has index 1 in $uppercase, and "a" has index = 1 in $smallcase, then all "A"s will be replaced with "a". Similarly, for "B","C" etc.
Now, when "," has index as 28 in $uppercase, but there is no character with index = 28 in $smallcase, hence "," is replaced with nothing.

Comment: So, you would put all characters you want to replace with "nothing" at the end of the UPPERCASE variable?

Comment: I have line returns in the data that are not based on "visible"  entities. Can I use "normalize-space" to get rid of those?